# Free alternative to Teamviewer?

Tags: windows, gratis, remote-desktop

I need an alternative to Teamviewer for Windows.
I have tried UltraVNC but it requires port forwarding and I don't have access to the router.

For some reason Teamviewer is asking me for a licence and I don't want to format my PC just for it, but I need remote access to that PC.
Teamviewer doesn't require any port forwarding and I need something similar.

Its need to be alternative to standard remote desktop, because i want to connect through the internet. It's for personal use and needs to be free. If i can't find an alternative i will just buy Teamviewer licence.

Comment: Please specify the details. Your question is quite unclear. Do you want a alternative to remote desktop connection app or something else?? How any PC's you want to connect(Business,Personal or Enterprise) ??? How much are you willing to pay for it(free,open-source)????

Comment: Just use UltraVNC and some gratis port-forwarding software. e.g. Hamachi

Comment: Teamviewer is free for personal use. It asks if you used it commercially but doesnt restrict you as far as i know. What exaxtly is your problem with teamviewer?

Comment: it just says my trial expired and i can't use it unless i pay

Comment: arti, please list all of your requirements. Somebody who has never heard about TeamViewer must be able to understand. See http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information