# Looking for a great Remote Desktop recommendation

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop

I'm looking for a reliable alternative to TeamViewer. I don't need it to be [open-source](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/51740/37051) or [free](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/26264/37051), I just need the following features:

(This is a long extensive list that I have in mind, please feel free to comment on or skip some, if you need to.)

- **Fast:** quick to connect, and *optimized* for low-latency viewing
- **Easy**: works with key forwarding out of the box, no need for additional dependencies, etc
- **Local network support**: allows connection to local network hosts (e.g. `192.168.1.0/24`)
- **Cross-platform:** works at least on Windows and modern Linux distros
- **Hi-DPI UI**: works with UI scaling properly
- **Unscaled client screen sharing:** ability to serve *unchanged* remote desktop
- **No screen flicker for the client:** e.g. mouse cursor flickering, window flickering, etc
- **Nice GUI**: modern, intuitive, updated looks (refer to screenshot below)
- **Installs as a service/daemon:** with startup and failure recovery
- **Unattended access:** starts hidden/minimized with a predefined access key with unrestricted remote access at any time
- **Concurrent connections:** allow multiple connections from different sources
- **Non-blocking:** Client should be able to view and interact with the desktop during the session
- **Maximum quality available:** don't purposefully limit quality when bandwidth is available
- **Login screen sharing:** e.g. in Windows, allows sharing the login screen and changing the user.
- **Syncronized clipboard:** I need text, image and file synchronization between host and client clipboards.
- **Audio redirecting**: ability to transfer client's audio
- **History of saved destinations:** keeps track of connected devices
- **Per-client password saving:** ability to save different passwords per user.
- **Send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> to the client**
- **Display client cursor:** ability to view the client user's mouse position.
- **Lock, Restart and Shutdown the client on demand**
- **Drag and drop transfer**

Here's *optional* features will be nice to have, but aren't mandatory:

- **Cut-off client's screen:** black out the screen
- **Disable client's user input:** disable mouse and keyboard input on demand
- **Disable remote's user input:** opposite of the above
- **Switch sides with partner:** allow reversing the client/remote sides
- **Audio call:** allow voice calling from/to the client
- **Lightweight:** total installation should be less than ~100mbs.
- **Automatic reconnect:** on case of connection loss.
- **Notify the client of incoming connections**
- **Interactive access:** allow connection from the client-side without need of a password
- **Allow random passwords in addition to a predefined password**
- **Whitelist and/or blacklist**
- **Change client resolution on demand**
- **Per-user connections (e.g. Windows Server OS)**
- **Share single windows instead of whole screen**
- **File transfer**
- **Nearby device discovery**
- **Backward/forward compatibilty** with older/newer protocols.
- **Prevent brute force attacks**
- **Integrated system health check**
- **Perform shell commands on the client**
- **Start new connection from cli (command-line) with parameters**
- **APIs for performing tasks or fetching events**
- **Seamless windows**
- **Built-in encryption**

Here's what I don't care about:

- Open-source. I don't care about this as long as it works reliably.
- Free. I don't care how much it costs as long as it's acquirable.
- VPN, Meeting, Remote printing, etc. I don't need business-related features.
- System resource utilization. Up to 40% cpu/ram utilization is fine by me.

[image: TeamViewer UI]

Comment: Did you look at TightVNC? It's the best, but, sorry, I don't have time to check it against your list of requirements. Give it a try

Comment: Thanks, but TightVNC lacks quite a lot of requirements. I appreciate your recommendation though :)

Comment: Wow, such as enormous feature list! I doubt that it even exists